# circle detection using python, numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, hough-transform

1. I want to implement hough transform algorithm using python, `numpy` and `scipy`.
2. I do not want to use `opencv`.
3. I am trying to detect Center of circle or circle in image without known radius.

How do I proceed?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform#Circle_Detection_Process

Comment: Also the Hough-transform example on Wikipedia from @H_shah assumes one specific radius, and does not detect circles of a generic radius, violating item 3.The idea is simple though, draw a circle of radius r on the empty canvas for each black pixel, the center of any same-radius circle in the original image will result a maximum on the canvas. This only detects circles of radius r.

Comment: I once was able to find the center of randomly sized circles using connected component analysis, I constructed bisections on pieces of the border of the circles and looked at the area('s) where many of these bisections intersected. The idea is described in slides 20-25 here: http://herbertkruitbosch.com/stuff/annual-rings-presentation.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The process of implementing the Hough Transform is pretty straightfoward. I suggest you look on youtube for some videos about it, there are even videos with code/pseudocode for it.

That being said, I've been in the same situation, looking to implement the HT to detect circles. However, the approach I decided to use was a bit different than the traditional HT. Instead of looping over all pixels to generate the circles that passes on at leat one of the circle points, I used the circle points as centers, incrementing the radius from min_radius to max_radius and accummulating it in the same form as the classic HT.

This way, you will end up having a 3D array with (x, y and radius used). The center and radius will be the (x, y, radius) with the maximum accummulated value.

[Simplified Hough Transform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyHqe.png)

Answer (score 1):

I have googled a bit and I found the following:

http://nabinsharma.wordpress.com/2012/12/26/linear-hough-transform-using-python/

Maybe this is what you are searching.

Sorry I think for circles you should try the following:

http://nullege.com/codes/search/houghcircles